# Mod Rewrite - hide .php, hide optional querystring

Tags: mod-rewrite

I figured out how to hide .php, but I need to hide any query string on the URL, and provide for there not being one.

Here's my current rule: `RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php`

I've searched everywhere, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a page that displays items from some kind of a lookup. So the requested resource is www.example.com/page.php?display=news.

In this case you can use something like `RewriteRule ^/news/$ page.php?display=news` This way you can create friendly URLs for different resources which might need a query string value passed in.

Lets say you want to make this generic. So display can have values news, about, company which map to the urls /news/ /about/ /company/ then you simply change your rule to

`RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?display=$1`

You can also use this second method to say change your shopping cart system's URLs to a friendly one. Say your shopping cart uses a query string like - shop.php?category=1&product=10. You can convert this into a URL like shop/category/1/product/10. The rule would be

`RewriteRule ^shop/category/([^/]+)/product/([^/]+)$ shop.php?category=$1&product=$2`